# Cannot fetch the rowset from OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "linked_server_name"

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000, sql-server-2016, linked-server

I have the same stored procedure on SQL Server 2000 and SQL Server 2016. The procedure itself inserts rows into a local #temporary table from local views that refer to tables on a linked server. The procedure runs successfully on the 2000 server (completed in about 20 minutes) while it crushes on the 2016 server after 3 hours with:

```
OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "linked_server_name" returned message "Unspecified error".
Cannot fetch the rowset from OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "linked_server_name". .
```

When I try to run simple SELECT queries on the 2016 server refering to the same linked server tables it works without any problems.

Comment: Similar problem here. I'm inserting from 2008 into 2016 and throws me your error. It all worked until a week ago.